# Multi-threading with Qt

Tags: qt, opencv

I am building a simple GUI in Qt to carry out some Image Processing in OpenCV. I want to use multi-threading so that the GUI is responsive even if the processing becomes very intensive. To do this I am referring the chapter below to build my framework:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405551&seqNum=3

To begin with, I have 2 push buttons, one to load the image and the other to process it.

I have 2 Labels, one to display the input image and one to display the processed image.

As of now, I am loading my input image using slot and signal mechanism in the main thread and I am creating a new thread for the image flip.

However, when I build my code, I get an error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "FlipTransaction::FlipTransaction(int)", referenced from:
>         MainWindow::flipHorizontally()       in mainwindow.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

When I comment out the slot flipHorizontally(), my code builds fine and am able to load the image.

Thus my processing is not being carried out.

Below is my code. Any help is appreciated

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QStatusBar>

// OpenCV Headers
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>   // for cvtColor

// Multi-Threading Headers
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QWaitCondition>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class Transaction
{
public:
    virtual ~Transaction() {}

    virtual QImage apply(const cv::Mat source_image, cv::Mat dest_image) = 0;

    virtual QString message() = 0;
};

class TransactionThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TransactionThread();
    ~TransactionThread();

    void addTransaction(Transaction *transact);
    void setImage(const QImage &image);
    QImage image();

signals:
    void transactionStarted(const QString &message);
    void allTransactionsDone();

protected:
    void run();

private:
    QImage currentImage;
    Transaction *EndTransaction;
    QQueue<Transaction *> transactions;
    QWaitCondition transactionAdded;
    QMutex mutex;
    cv::Mat source_image;
    cv::Mat dest_image;
};


class FlipTransaction : public Transaction
{
public:
    FlipTransaction(int orientation);

    QImage apply(const cv::Mat source_image, cv::Mat dest_image);
    QString message();

private:
    int orientation;
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void addTransaction(Transaction *transact);
    void drawOut(QImage qimg);


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

public slots:
    void flipHorizontally();
    void allTransactionsDone();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public:
    TransactionThread thread;
    cv::Mat source_image;       // Input Image Variable
    cv::Mat dest_image;         // Output Image Variable
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Ready"), 2000);

    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(transactionStarted(const QString &)),
            statusBar(), SLOT(showMessage(const QString &)));

    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(allTransactionsDone()),
            this, SLOT(allTransactionsDone()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::drawOut(QImage qimg)
{
    // Display on Label
    ui->outputLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));

    // Resize the label to fit the image
    ui->outputLabel->resize(ui->outputLabel->pixmap()->size());
}


void MainWindow::addTransaction(Transaction *transact)
{
      MainWindow::thread.addTransaction(transact);
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open Image"), ".",tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)"));

    // Read Image
    source_image = cv::imread(filename.toAscii().data());

    // Resize Image
    cv::resize(source_image, source_image, cv::Size(128,128) , 0, 0);

    // Change to RGB format
    cv::cvtColor(source_image,source_image,CV_BGR2RGB);

    // Convert to QImage
    QImage qimg = QImage((const unsigned char*) source_image.data, source_image.cols, source_image.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888); // convert to QImage

    // Display on Input Label
    ui->inputLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimg));

    // Resize the label to fit the image
    ui->inputLabel->resize(ui->inputLabel->pixmap()->size());
}


void MainWindow::flipHorizontally()
{
    MainWindow::thread.addTransaction(new FlipTransaction(int(1)));
}


void MainWindow::allTransactionsDone()
{
    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Ready"), 2000);
}

TransactionThread::TransactionThread()
{
    start();
}

TransactionThread::~TransactionThread()
{
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        while(!transactions.isEmpty())
            delete transactions.dequeue();
        transactions.enqueue(EndTransaction);
        transactionAdded.wakeOne();
    }
    wait();
}

void TransactionThread::addTransaction(Transaction *transact)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    transactions.enqueue(transact);
    transactionAdded.wakeOne();
}

void TransactionThread::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    currentImage = image;
}

QImage TransactionThread::image()
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    return currentImage;
}

void TransactionThread::run()
{
    Transaction *transact = 0;
    QImage oldImage;

    forever {
        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

            if (transactions.isEmpty())
                transactionAdded.wait(&mutex);
            transact = transactions.dequeue();
            if (transact == EndTransaction)
                break;

            oldImage = currentImage;
        }

        emit transactionStarted(transact->message());

        QImage newImage = transact->apply(source_image, dest_image);

     //   QImage newImage = transact->apply(oldImage);
        delete transact;

        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
            currentImage = newImage;
            if (transactions.isEmpty())
                emit allTransactionsDone();
        }

    }
}

QImage FlipTransaction::apply(const cv::Mat source_image, cv::Mat dest_image)
{
    // Process Image
    cv::flip(source_image, dest_image, orientation);

    // Change to RGB format
    cv::cvtColor(dest_image,dest_image,CV_BGR2RGB);

    // Convert to QImage
    QImage qimg = QImage((const unsigned char*) dest_image.data, dest_image.cols, dest_image.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    return qimg;
}


QString FlipTransaction::message()
{
    if (orientation == 1) {
        return QObject::tr("Flipping image horizontally...");
    } else {
        return QObject::tr("Flipping image vertically...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code for the constructor `FlipTransaction(int orientation);` ?

Comment: @Mat: I was just about to ask that. I see the declaration but no code for the constructor.